# Next steps to proceed with the Shopify Laravel App

Tags: php, laravel, shopify-app

I need to build an App in Laravel that, when installed in the Online Store, needs to add a new external payment method, what are the recommendations and steps to be followed?
I'm doing it with the Kyon147/laravel-shopify package.

I've already done the App Bridge but now I need a way to add the external payment method, what would be the next steps?